# OnePlus Buds Z2 Bluetooth connected but not recognized as headset and microphone in Ubuntu 20.0.4 LTS

Tags: networking, sound, bluetooth

I recently bought the Oneplus Buds Z2 TWS. It is perfectly working with windows 10 but in my work laptop which has Ubuntu 20.0.4, the buds are not working. I can connect it via Bluetooth and that's it. It doesn't recognize the buds as headphone or mic. I am pretty new to Ubuntu. How can I fix this problem?

Here's the screenshots:

[Bluetooth Connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT4hg.png)

[Can't find any option to select the buds as headset or mic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rvkj.png)

Comment: To be clear you connect them and there is no Bluetooth devices what so ever in the list of Bluetooth devices? If so how do you know they are connected?

Comment: I can connect them via bluetooth. I've provided the bluetooth connected screenshot. I can't select the buds as headset or mic in sound settings.

Comment: That is not the device connection screen that I see on Ubuntu 20.04 (the actual version number). Go to system settings and click on the Bluetooth icon. The screen you showed says it is for file transfer.

Comment: Same problem here, you find any solutions?

Comment: I solved installing ofono with apt install ofono

Comment: In my case, I couldn't even pair the buds Z2 with the system, then I installed ofono as @Ciro Spaciari mentioned in the comments. Then I was able to pair the buds Z2 as a Bluetooth device. But Ubuntu is not recognizing it as an audio device.

Comment: You tried remove the device and connect via blueman-manager? (in my case show up 2 devices a non headset device and a headset device, connecting in the non headset will not recognize, but in the headset will)

Comment: When I connected via Blueman-manager, now it's working. Thank you.

Comment: For future visitors, the following worked for me: `sudo apt install ofono blueman` and then connecting the headset with blueman manager worked for me.